# How can I draw rectangles with D3js which are placed like wall bricks structure?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

[image]

I am very new to D3js and I wan to draw something like this as per the images attached. So my requirement is SVG rectangles are placed such a way that which are look like wall bricks with random data.

Your help must be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add what you have tried so far (maybe the code will be better), what problem you are facing in that.

Comment: try for d3.select('#svghandle')
  .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 320)
    .attr('height', 250)
    .style('background', '#fcf8e3')
   .append('polygon')
     .attr('points', '150, 105 300, 105 325, 130 325, 200 300, 225 150, 225 125, 200 125, 130')
    .style({ 'stroke': '#8a6d3b', 'stroke-width': '25px', 'fill': '#faebcc' });

Comment: @LDS Thanks for sharing. It will really help me a lot. But I want that bricks like rectangles positioning randomly. Appreciate for your answer.

Comment: yes can do that by just changing the angles

Comment: take multile octangles in a div

Comment: Are you able to make basic rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to draw bricks in D3.

```js
// array = input array
// part = size of the chunk
function splitArray(array, part) {
    var tmp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += part) {
        tmp.push(array.slice(i, i + part));
    }
    return tmp;
}

// Create range
const margin = { left: 10, top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10 };
const vals = [...Array(12).keys()].map(i => `rect val ${i}`);
const layers = 3;
const brickSize = { height: 60, width: 100 };
const cement = { thickness: 5 };

const valsReshaped = splitArray(vals, layers);

const svg = d3.select('#wall')
    .attr('width', (valsReshaped[0].length + 0.5) * (brickSize.width + cement.thickness) + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', valsReshaped.length * (brickSize.height + cement.thickness) + margin.top + margin.bottom);

const wall = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

const layer = wall.selectAll('g.layer')
    .data(valsReshaped).enter()
  .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'layer')
    .attr('transform', (d, i) => {
        const x = (i % 2) * (brickSize.width + cement.thickness) * 0.5;
        const y = i * (brickSize.height + cement.thickness); 
        return `translate(${x},${y})`;
    });
  
const bricks = layer.selectAll('g.brick')
    .data(d => d).enter()
  .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'brick')
    .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${i * (brickSize.width + cement.thickness)},0)`);

bricks.selectAll('rect')
    .data(d => [d]).enter()
  .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'brick')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('rx', 10)
    .attr('ry', 10)
    .attr('width', brickSize.width)
    .attr('height', brickSize.height);

bricks.selectAll('text')
    .data(d => [d]).enter()
  .append('text')
    .attr('x', (brickSize.width + cement.thickness) / 2)
    .attr('y', (brickSize.height + cement.thickness) / 2)
    .text(d => d);
```

```css
.brick > rect {
  fill: #aa3311;
  stroke: darkred;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
.brick > text {
  fill: white;
  text-anchor: middle;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="wall"></svg>
```

Comment: Excellent. Exactly the same what I am trying for. Appreciate. Thank you very much.